# Drawing a rectangle using CLX

Tags: common-lisp, x11

I am trying to draw a rectangle inside a window using Common Lisp X Interface:

```
(asdf:load-system "clx")

(in-package :xlib)

(defun main ()
  (let* ((display (open-default-display))
         (screen (display-default-screen display))
         (colormap (screen-default-colormap screen))
         (font (open-font display "fixed")))
    (let* ((window (create-window
                    :parent (screen-root screen)
                    :x 0
                    :y 0
                    :width 512
                    :height 512
            :border (screen-black-pixel screen)
            :border-width 2
            :bit-gravity :center
            :colormap colormap
                    :background (alloc-color colormap
                                             (lookup-color colormap
                                                                     "white"))))
           (foreground (create-gcontext
                        :drawable window
                        :fill-style :solid
                        :background (screen-white-pixel screen)
                        :foreground (alloc-color colormap
                                                      (lookup-color
                                                       colormap
                                                       "red"))
                        :font font)))
      (map-window window)
      (unwind-protect
       (progn
         (draw-rectangle window foreground 0 0 100 100 :fill-p) ;; no effect
         (display-force-output display)
         (display-finish-output display)
         (sleep 2))
    (CLOSE-DISPLAY display)))))
```

What I get is just an empty window. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: can you add a t to :fill-p option? like this:
(draw-rectangle window foreground 0 0 100 100 :fill-p t)

Comment: No, because it violates the function signature. CLX defines #'draw-rectangle as (draw-rectangle drawable gcontext x y width height &optional fill-p), so one cannot add one more additional parameter. One can put t instead of :fill-p and it compiles. But it has no effect either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. After playing with your code a considerable time, I made it work within a loop. It seems like clx wants you to perform the drawing at least once? Here, it works if you replace your progn with a loop for example:

```
...
(unwind-protect
       (loop repeat 3
             do
         (draw-rectangle window foreground 0 0 100 100 :fill-p) ;; no effect
         (display-force-output display)
         ;;(display-finish-output display)
         (sleep 1))
    (CLOSE-DISPLAY display)))))
```